# Why exec function in python adds '.!' at the beginning of the text?

Tags: python, tkinter, exec, tkinter-label

I am currently working on a hangman game using tkinter in python.

When I click a button of the letter and it is in the word that we are guessing it should show the letter. But when I click the button this problem is popping up:

This example is only with one button. People say that this problem is because of the mainloop(), but i have no idea how to fix it.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from generate_word import word

#DEFAULT VALUES
score = 0
count = 0
win_count = 2
WINDOW_BG = '#e5404e'
WINDOW_SIZE = '1200x870+300+80'
FONT = ('Arial', 40)
    from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from generate_word import word

#DEFAULT VALUES
score = 0
count = 0
win_count = 2
WINDOW_BG = '#e5404e'
WINDOW_SIZE = '1200x870+300+80'
FONT = ('Arial', 40)
#this is an example with only one button
buttons = [['b1','a',80,740]]


#Creating window and configurating it
window = Tk()
window.geometry(WINDOW_SIZE)
window.title('Hangman')
window.config(bg = WINDOW_BG)

#generates all of the labels for the word
def gen_labels_word():
    label = Label(window, text = " ", bg = WINDOW_BG, font = FONT)
    label.pack( padx = 40,pady = (500,100),side = LEFT)

    label1 = Label(window, text = word[0], bg = WINDOW_BG, font = FONT)
    label1.pack( padx = 41,pady = (500,100),side = LEFT)

    x = 21
    for var in range(1,len(word)): 
        exec('label{}=Label(window,text="_",bg=WINDOW_BG,font=FONT)'.format(var))
        exec('label{}.pack(padx = {}, pady = (500,100), side=LEFT)'.format(var,x))
        x += 1

    exec('label{} = Label(window, text = "{}", bg = WINDOW_BG, font = FONT)'.format(len(word),word[-1]))
    exec('label{}.pack( padx = {},pady = (500,100),side = LEFT)'.format(len(word), x+1))              



# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

gen_labels_word()

#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#letters icons(images)       


#hangman (images)
hangman = ['h0','h1','h2','h3','h4','h5','h6']
for var in hangman:
    exec(f'{var}=PhotoImage(file="{var}.png")')

han = [['label0','h0'],['label1','h1'],['label2','h2'],['label3','h3'],['label4','h4'],['label5','h5'],['label6','h6']]
for p1 in han:
    exec('{}=Label(window, bg = WINDOW_BG ,image={})'.format(p1[0],p1[1]))
exec('label0.place(x = 620,y = 0)')

for var in letters:
        exec(f'{var}=PhotoImage(file="{var}.png")')
for var in buttons:
        exec(f'{var[0]}=Button(window,bd=0,command=lambda: game_brain("{var[0]}","{var[1]}"),bg = WINDOW_BG,font=FONT,image={var[1]})')
        exec('{}.place(x={},y={})'.format(var[0],var[2],var[3]))




def game_brain(button, letter):
        global count,win_count,score
        exec('{}.destroy()'.format(button))
        if letter in word:
            for i in range(1,len(word)):
                if word[i] == letter:
                    win_count += 1
                    exec(f'label{i}.config(text="{letter}")')
            if win_count == len(word):
                score += 1
                messagebox.showinfo('GOOD JOB, YOU WON!\n GOODBYE!')
                window.destroy()

        else:
            count += 1
            exec('label{}.destroy()'.format(count-1))
            exec('label{}.place(x={},y={})'.format(count,620,0))
            if count == 6:
                messagebox.showinfo('GAME OVER','YOU LOST!\nGOODBYE!')
                window.destroy()

                
def EXIT():
    answer = messagebox.askyesno('ALERT','Do you want to exit the game?')
    if answer == True:
        window.destroy()

e1 = PhotoImage(file = 'exit.png')
ex = Button(window,bd = 0,command = EXIT,bg = WINDOW_BG,font = FONT,image = e1)
ex.place(x=1050,y=20)
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: You shouldn't be using `exec` to create widgets, largely because of problems like this -- it makes your code impossible to debug. You can store the labels in a dictionary: `label[var] = Label(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

> Why exec function in python adds '.!' at the beginning of the text?

The `exec` function isn't doing that. Tkinter by default names all of its widgets with a leading exclamation point. When you print out a widget, it has to be converted to a string. For tkinter widgets, the result of `str(some_widget)` is the widget's name.

You can see this quite easily without exec:

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
label = tk.Label(root)
print(label)
```

The above will print something like `.!label`. If you create a second label it will be `.!label2`, a third will be `.!label3` and so on.

---

On an unrelated note, you shouldn't be using `exec` to create widgets. It makes the code very hard to understand and debug. If you want to create widgets in a loop, add them to a dictionary or list instead of dynamically creating variables with `exec`.

For example:

```
    labels = {}
    for var in range(1,len(word)): 
        label = Label(window,text="_",bg=WINDOW_BG,font=FONT)
        label.pack(padx=500, pady=100)
        labels[var] = label
```

With that, you can later reference the widgets as `labels[1]`, `labels[2]`, etc.

You should do the same thing with the images, or anything else that you create in a loop and want to keep track of.